# How nodejs handles global module being used in multiple applications running in parallel?

Tags: node.js

I have created very simple nodejs hello application.

```
//hello.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var config = require('./config');

console.log(config.getConfig());
config.setConfig(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 );
console.log(config.getConfig());

var readconfig = require('./readconfig');

console.log("Hi !! I am glad to see you again");

//config.js
var config;

exports.getConfig = function(){
    return config;
}

exports.setConfig = function(c){
    config = c;
}

//package.json
"bin": {
    "hello": "hello.js"
  }

//readconfig.js
var config = require('./config');

console.log(config.getConfig());
config.setConfig(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 );
console.log(config.getConfig());
```

I had installed my sample module globally. And when I run 'hello' command from different folders, or multiple times from the same folder, I ever get;

```
undefined
2 //some random number
2 //some random number
4 //some random number
Hi !! I am glad to see you again
```

From the above response it looks like, nodejs cache a local module but maintain different copy for each application context. However I am not sure.

Can somebody plz explain how exactly nodejs handles global modules and separate their variables from all the applications using it?

Comment: can you post config.js ?

Comment: yeah it is mentioned in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each node application is completely independent of the others.  They are separate processes, completely separate modules, each loading independently, sharing no data.

Within a given application, a module loaded with `require()` is cached.  The first time the module is loaded with `require()` it is loaded from disk and initialized.  From then on, any subsequent requests to load that module just return the same module handle that was previously loaded - it doesn't load it again or run it again.

The `require()` module loader maintains a cache.  Once a module is loaded it is then in the cache and any subsequent requests to load it (from with that specific application) just return the cached module handle.